# Смещение текущей позиции BinaryWriter

Tags: c#

Собственно, есть процедура записи нескольких файлов в один посредством BinaryWriter (C#). После каждой такой записи позиция в записываемом файле смещается согласно размеру входного файла. Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы после каждой записи позиция смещалась вперёд. Сейчас объясню на примере:

Файл размером 0x0A(10 байт) записывается в новый (выходной) файл и после записи позиция "врайтера" равна 0x0A. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы следующий файл записывался с позиции 0x10. И так для каждого файла, при записи мне нужно рассчитать новую позицию так, чтобы она начиналась с позиции 00 в хекс-редакторе (к примеру, 0x110, 0x6A0, 0x21F0 - то есть позиция всегда оканчивается на 0 в формате hex).

Всем спасибо! Удалось реализовать таким образом: `(0x10 - offset % 0x10) + offset`

Comment: Ну записывайте туда дополнительно нулевой (или любой другой) байт. Там же что-то должно быть в файле в этом месте. Или вы хотите сохранить то, что там есть сейчас в выходном файле в этом байте?

Comment: Как вариант, используйте свойство `BaseStream`, а у него либо свойство `Position`, либо метод `Seek`.

Comment: Пропущенные байты так и должны иметь 0x00. Дело в том, что с каждой записью конечная позиция разная, ведь у файлов разный размер. Мне нужно чтобы каждый файл в массиве байт начинался с нулевой позиции в хекс-редакторе (например, 0x10, 0x20, 0xF0, 0x100,  и т.д.)

Comment: Во время считывания такого файла, чтобы пропустить нулевые байты я использовал код while (reader.ReadByte() == 0x00) { } 
reader.BaseStream.Position -= 1;

Comment: Деление по модулю поможет определить нужную позицию: `% 16`.